# Graph in C++ using gnuPlot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am using gnuPlot library for printing a graph in C++ code. Its printing graph fine, but its printing only in blue color. Does somebody know how can I change the colors?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linestyle for setting a color. Some examples are [here](http://nucl.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/~ohnishi/Lib/gnuplot.html).